# Get N different values from CSV data set config in each iteration

Tags: performance, jmeter

I have the following Jmeter Test Plan

```
Thread Group
    -Java Request
    -CSV Data set config(Sharing mode :current thread group)
View Results Tree
```

The Java Request has code to process the N values at a time.
Each value from the CSV file must be used only once.
For eg , if

```
 no of entries in CSV file: 1000
    threads : 10
    loop count :10 
    N=entries to process in each iteration =10[calculated as :(no of entries in CSV)/(threads)/(loop count)]
```

So in each iteration, each thread must take 10 entries at once and pass it to the Java Request.

I have the following questions:

1. How to make each iteration take N different values from CSV ?
2. How to pass these N values to the Java request as a parameter?
3. My end objective is to measure how fast all the entries are
   processed with the given number of threads and loop count.  I am
   using Jmeter to make use of the threadgroups and obtain the
   throughput. If there is a better way to do this ,please suggest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Amend your test plan as follows:

- Thread Group

  - Loop Controller (loop count = 10)

    - [Counter](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Counter)
    - [Beanshell Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#BeanShell_Sampler)
    - CSV Data Set Config
  - Java Request

In the Beanshell Sampler you need to put custom code which will read value from the CSV Data Set Config and add it to JMeter Variables, something like:

```
var1=foo
var2=bar
...
var10=something
```

So you could pass these 10 variables to the Java Request Sampler as `${var1}`, `${var2}`, etc.

See [How to use BeanShell: JMeter's favorite built-in component](https://blazemeter.com/blog/queen-jmeters-built-componentshow-use-beanshell) guide for information on scripting.

Pseudo-code will look like:

```
String postfix = vars.get("POSTFIX"); // where POSTFIX is Reference name of Counter

String value = vars.get("VALUE"); // where VALUE is the Variable Name defined in CSV Data Set

vars.put("var" + postfix, value); // put current value read form CSV file into varX JMeter Variable
```

Comment: All the 10 values are for the same variable, is there a way I could pass all 10 values in an array to the Java request instead of sending 10 different variables?

Comment: Not sure that I'm correctly getting your question. Why don't just send one variable 10 times?

Answer (score 0):

I modified the test plan as mentioned above and sent just a single variable to Java Sampler by using the following code in Beanshell Sampler -

```
String postfix = vars.get("POSTFIX");  // where POSTFIX is Reference name of Counter
String value = vars.get("VALUE");     // where VALUE is the Variable Name defined in CSV Data Set
vars.put("var" + postfix, value);     // put current value read form CSV file into varX JMeter Variable
// all the 10 values are concatenated to the input variable ,and is the single variable sent to the Java Sampler  
  if(postfix.equals("1"))
    vars.put("input",vars.get("var"+postfix));  
    else
    vars.put("input",vars.get("input")+","+vars.get("var"+postfix));
```